# How do you manage deterministic finalization in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a C# object with a critical resource that needs to be flushed very specific points  in time making it a bad candidate to leave around for the garbage collector to take care of whenever it gets around to it, how should I handle this?  Is there something like C++'s delete operator that will let me manually kill the instance of this object when needed?

Answer (score 22):

You are looking for [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). Here is an example class that implements this.

```
class MyDisposableObject : IDisposable
{
   public MyDisposableObject()
   {
   }

   ~MyDisposableObject()
   {
      Dispose(false);
   }

   private bool disposed;
   private void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (!this.disposed)
      {
          if (disposing)
          {
             // Dispose of your managed resources here.
          }

          // Dispose of your unmanaged resources here.

          this.disposed = true;
       }
   }

   void IDisposable.Dispose()
   {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
}
```

To use it, you can do something like this:

```
public void DoingMyThing()
{
   using (MyDisposableObject obj = new MyDisposableObject())
   {
      // Use obj here.
   }
}
```

The [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword makes sure that the [`Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method on [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) gets called at the end of its scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what the [`IDiposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface is for. You release the critical resources in the `Dispose()` method, and then leave the object around for the garbage disposer to deal with deallocating the memory.

Answer (score 2):

The IDisposable interface exists for deterministic destruction.  There's a pattern for implementing it correctly on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).

In tandem, you should also consider using the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) when your object's lifetime does not span multiple scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Google for the IDisposable interface.  This is the only mechanism available to you.  It's tailor made if your critical resource is unmanaged.  If it's a managed resource, could you be more specific about what needs to be "flushed".

Answer (score 0):

The IDisposable interface was added to support deterministic destruction in C++/CLI, and you can use it from any .NET language. It's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a specific managed resource that you feel "MUST" be released at a specific time, you could specifcally call the Garbage Collectors' Collect method, after de-referencing the object, but there are performance considerations to be thought of, as normally the garbage collector knows when to collect items.  And in general it is a bad idea.

As others are mentioning above, the IDisposable pattern is helpful for releasing unmanaged resources when needed.

**NOTE:** I'm going to repeat, you COULD call GC.Collect() but it is NOT a good thing, but a valid answer for the question!

Comment: Don't call GC.Collect().  Bad habit to get into, and is usually more detrimental than useful.

Comment: I know that...thus my note about not using it.