# WPF window class destruction

Tags: c#, wpf, window, destructor

I create a window like this:

```
if (someCondition)   
{  
   MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow();  
   wnd.Owner = this;  
   wnd.ShowDialog();  
}
```

I want MyWindow's destructor to be called at the closing curly bracket, but it doesn't.  Do I need to call something like delete/destroy for MyWindow's destructor to be called?

Comment: Why do you need to call the destructor? If you're doing simple clean-up work, have MyWindow implement IDisposable and do the clean-up in the Dispose method. I don't believe using the destructor is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "destructor" or [finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28VS.71%29.aspx) as it is called in C# is called whenever the Garbage Collector feels like. You can trigger the Garbage Collector manually using [System.GC.Collect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect.aspx), but [you probably don't want to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233596/best-practice-for-forcing-garbage-collection-in-c/233647#233647). If your talking about Dispose() on the other hand you can make this being called by creating the window in a "using" clause:

```
using (var wnd = new MyWindow())
{
    wnd.Owner = this;  
    wnd.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

This would make wnd.Dispose() be called when the using clause is done, and would basically be the same as writing:

```
var wnd = new MyWindow(); 
wnd.Owner = this;  
wnd.ShowDialog();     
wnd.Dispose();
```

About the usage of the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339063/what-is-the-difference-between-using-idisposable-vs-a-destructor-in-c) might be helpful - and [several more on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+idisposable).

Answer (score 1):

```
using (MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow())
{
   wnd.Owner = this;
   wnd.ShowDialog();
}
```

This will call `Dispose` on your window after the curly brace, which is what I think you are looking for. Your `MyWindow` class will need to implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Not to be excessively pedantic, but the class already implements `IDisposable`; what it's going to need to do is override `Dispose`.

Comment: Robert: The WPF Window class doesn't implement IDisposable.  (It doesn't hold any unmanaged resources.)  Charlie's right, IDisposable needs to be implemented on the MyWindow derived class.

Answer (score 0):

One little thing, you're opening the window and then wanting call it's destructor.  That doesn't really make sense.  You should close the Window and then it's destructor will be called implicitly.

If you want to call it explicitly you should override Dispose in your MyWindow class. There you can clean up any resources that you want to explicitly dispose off.

Comment: `ShowDialog` doesn't return until the Windows is closed - so I don't understand your answer?

Comment: so if 'ShowDialog' doesn't return until the dialog is closed, how can one call the destructor if the dialog is still not destroyed?  That's the point I'm trying to make.