# Do you need to dispose of objects and set them to null?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, dispose

Do you need to dispose of objects and set them to null, or will the garbage collector clean them up when they go out of scope?

Comment: There appears to be a consensus that you don't need to set the object to null, but do you need to do Dispose()?

Comment: Yes, that's about right.

Comment: as Jeff said: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/die-you-gravy-sucking-pig-dog.html

Comment: My advice is always dispose if an object implements IDisposable. Use a using block every time. Don't make assumptions, don't leave it up to chance. You don't have to set things to null though. An object just has go go out of scope.

Comment: @peter: Don't use "using" blocks with WCF client proxies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: **HOWEVER, YOU MAY** want to set some references to null inside your `Dispose()` method! This is a subtle variation on this question, but important because the object being disposed can't know if it is "going out of scope" (calling `Dispose()` is no guarantee). More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757048/msdn-dispose-example-erroneous-when-to-set-managed-references-to-null

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Objects will be cleaned up when they are no longer being used and when the garbage collector sees fit.  Sometimes, you may need to set an object to `null` in order to make it go out of scope (such as a static field whose value you no longer need), but overall there is usually no need to set to `null`.

Regarding disposing objects, I agree with @Andre.  If the object is `IDisposable` it is **a good idea to dispose it** when you no longer need it, especially if the object uses unmanaged resources. Not disposing unmanaged resources will **lead to memory leaks**.

You can use the `using` statement to automatically dispose an object once your program leaves the scope of the `using` statement.

```
using (MyIDisposableObject obj = new MyIDisposableObject())
{
    // use the object here
} // the object is disposed here
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
MyIDisposableObject obj;
try
{
    obj = new MyIDisposableObject();
}
finally
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: One remark regarding `IDisposable`. Failing to Dispose an object will generally **not cause a memory leak** on any well designed class. When working with unmanaged resources in C# you should have a finalizer that will still release the unmanaged resources. This means that instead of deallocating the resources when it should be done, it will be deferred to when the garbage collector finalizes the managed object. It can still cause many other issues though (such as unreleased locks). You should Dispose an `IDisposable` though!

Comment: @RandyLevy Do you have a reference for that? Thanks

Comment: But my question is Dispose() needs to implement any logic? Does it have to do something? Or internally when Dispose() is called signals GC that is good to go? I checked the source code for the TextWriter for example and   Dispose has no implementation.

Comment: @Mihail I haven't been doing C# lately so I could be a bit rusty, but IIRC there's nothing special about Dispose and the garbage collector, it's just a pattern in C# to release resources before the garbage collector gets around to finalizing your object. If you have a finalizer, make sure to call GC.SuppressFinalize(this) inside dispose so GC doesn't have to do more work than necessary.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ZachJohnson thank you for your answer. Yes I know Microsoft's pattern , I know that the destructor aka finalizer is used to to get rid of unmanaged  resoures , and Dispose() is used to do both using Microsoft's pattern, but I was wondering if we acually NEED to do something about the managed resources , we all know , if a reference is out of scope the object is good to go and GC will collect it at some time. I am a bit confused , do I have to nullify the references or something , does that even help at all? I am a bit confused. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mihail you shouldn't need to worry about managed resources, or nulling things out (unless they're being referenced directly or indirectly via a static field - a memory profiler can help out here)

Comment: @ZachJohnson makes sense! Thank you very much sir! Cheers!

Answer (score 147):

Objects never go out of scope in C# as they do in C++. They are dealt with by the Garbage Collector automatically when they are not used anymore. This is a more complicated approach than C++ where the scope of a variable is entirely deterministic. CLR garbage collector actively goes through all objects that have been created and works out if they are being used.

An object can go "out of scope" in one function but if its value is returned, then GC would look at whether or not the calling function holds onto the return value.

Setting object references to `null` is unnecessary as garbage collection works by working out which objects are being referenced by other objects.

In practice, you don't have to worry about destruction, it just works and it's great :)

`Dispose` must be called on all objects that implement `IDisposable` when you are finished working with them. Normally you would use a `using` block with those objects like so:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
  //...
}
```

**EDIT** On variable scope. Craig has asked whether the variable scope has any effect on the object lifetime. To properly explain that aspect of CLR, I'll need to explain a few concepts from C++ and C#.

#### Actual variable scope

In both languages the variable can only be used in the same scope as it was defined - class, function or a statement block enclosed by braces. The subtle difference, however, is that in C#, variables cannot be redefined in a nested block.

In C++, this is perfectly legal:

```
int iVal = 8;
//iVal == 8
if (iVal == 8){
    int iVal = 5;
    //iVal == 5
}
//iVal == 8
```

In C#, however you get a a compiler error:

```
int iVal = 8;
if(iVal == 8) {
    int iVal = 5; //error CS0136: A local variable named 'iVal' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'iVal', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
}
```

This makes sense if you look at generated MSIL - all the variables used by the function are defined at the start of the function. Take a look at this function:

```
public static void Scope() {
    int iVal = 8;
    if(iVal == 8) {
        int iVal2 = 5;
    }
}
```

Below is the generated IL. Note that iVal2, which is defined inside the if block is actually defined at function level. Effectively this means that C# only has class and function level scope as far as variable lifetime is concerned.

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Scope() cil managed
{
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 iVal,
           [1] int32 iVal2,
           [2] bool CS$4$0000)

//Function IL - omitted
} // end of method Test2::Scope
```

#### C++ scope and object lifetime

Whenever a C++ variable, allocated on the stack, goes out of scope it gets destructed. Remember that in C++ you can create objects on the stack or on the heap. When you create them on the stack, once execution leaves the scope, they get popped off the stack and gets destroyed.

```
if (true) {
  MyClass stackObj; //created on the stack
  MyClass heapObj = new MyClass(); //created on the heap
  obj.doSomething();
} //<-- stackObj is destroyed
//heapObj still lives
```

When C++ objects are created on the heap, they must be explicitly destroyed, otherwise it is a memory leak. No such problem with stack variables though.

#### C# Object Lifetime

In CLR, objects (i.e. reference types) are **always** created on the managed heap. This is further reinforced by object creation syntax. Consider this code snippet.

```
MyClass stackObj;
```

In C++ this would create an instance on `MyClass` on the stack and call its default constructor. In C# it would create a reference to class `MyClass` that doesn't point to anything. The only way to create an instance of a class is by using `new` operator:

```
MyClass stackObj = new MyClass();
```

In a way, C# objects are a lot like objects that are created using `new` syntax in C++ - they are created on the heap but unlike C++ objects, they are managed by the runtime, so you don't have to worry about destructing them.

Since the objects are **always** on the heap the fact that object references (i.e. pointers) go out of scope becomes moot. There are more factors involved in determining if an object is to be collected than simply presence of references to the object.

#### C# Object references

Jon Skeet [compared object references in Java](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html) to pieces of string that are attached to the balloon, which is the object. Same analogy applies to C# object references. They simply point to a location of the heap that contains the object. Thus, setting it to null has no immediate effect on the object lifetime, the balloon continues to exist, until the GC "pops" it.

Continuing down the balloon analogy, it would seem logical that once the balloon has no strings attached to it, it can be destroyed. In fact this is exactly how reference counted objects work in non-managed languages. Except this approach doesn't work for circular references very well. Imagine two balloons that are attached together by a string but neither balloon has a string to anything else. Under simple ref counting rules, they both continue to exist, even though the whole balloon group is "orphaned".

.NET objects are a lot like helium balloons under a roof. When the roof opens (GC runs) - the unused balloons float away, even though there might be groups of balloons that are tethered together.

.NET GC uses a combination of generational GC and mark and sweep. Generational approach involves the runtime favouring to inspect objects that have been allocated most recently, as they are more likely to be unused and mark and sweep involves runtime going through the whole object graph and working out if there are object groups that are unused. This adequately deals with circular dependency problem.

Also, .NET GC runs on another thread(so called finalizer thread) as it has quite a bit to do and doing that on the main thread would interrupt your program.

Comment: @Igor: By going 'out of scope' I mean that the object reference is out of context and cannot be referred to in the current scope.  Surely this still happens in C#.

Comment: @Craig Johnston, don't confuse variable scoping used by the compiler with variable lifetime which is determined by the runtime -- they are different.  A local variable may not be "live" even though it is still in scope.

Comment: @Tuzo: you will need to elaborate. The only kind of scoping I am talking about is the scoping that makes a variable local to a function go out of scope when the functions finishes. What is the other kind of scoping?

Comment: @Craig Johnston: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/07/23/192842.aspx : "there is no guarantee that a local variable will remain live until the end of a scope if it isn't used. The runtime is free to analyze the code that it has and determine what there are no further usages of a variable beyond a certain point, and therefore not keep that variable live beyond that point (ie not treat it as a root for the purposes of GC)."

Comment: @Tuzo: True.  That's what GC.KeepAlive is for.

Comment: @Tuzo: Is the 'life' of a variable of any relevance to the programmer?  It sounds like something that happens well after the programmer has written and compiled the code.

Comment: @Craig Johnston: No and Yes.  No because the .NET runtime manages that for you and does a good job.  Yes because the job of the programmer is not to write code that (just) compiles but to write code that *runs*.  Sometimes it helps to know what the runtime is doing under the covers (e.g. troubleshooting).  One could argue that it's the type of knowledge that helps to separate good programmers from great programmers.

Comment: Well, just like the rest of the program, variable lifetime is inherently a run-time characteristic of a program. Yes it happens after the programmer wrote the code, but just like any code, the programmer has some control over the runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 20):

As others have said you definitely want to call `Dispose` if the class implements `IDisposable`. I take a fairly rigid position on this. Some might claim that calling `Dispose` on `DataSet`, for example, is pointless because they disassembled it and saw that it did not do anything meaningful. But, I think there are fallacies abound in that argument.

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kimhamil/when-to-call-dispose) for an interesting debate by respected individuals on the subject. Then read my reasoning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339063/what-is-the-difference-between-using-idisposable-vs-a-destructor-in-c/1400372#1400372) why I think Jeffery Richter is in the wrong camp.

Now, on to whether or not you should set a reference to `null`. The answer is no. Let me illustrate my point with the following code.

```
public static void Main()
{
  Object a = new Object();
  Console.WriteLine("object created");
  DoSomething(a);
  Console.WriteLine("object used");
  a = null;
  Console.WriteLine("reference set to null");
}
```

So when do you think the object referenced by `a` is eligible for collection? If you said after the call to `a = null` then you are wrong. If you said after the `Main` method completes then you are also wrong. The correct answer is that it is eligible for collection sometime **during** the call to `DoSomething`. That is right. It is eligible **before** the reference is set to `null` and perhaps even before the call to `DoSomething` completes. That is because the JIT compiler can recognize when object references are no longer dereferenced even if they are still rooted.

Comment: What if `a` is a private member field in a class? If `a` is not set to null the GC has no way of knowing if `a` will be used again in some method, right? Thus `a` will not be collected until the entire containing class is collected. No?

Comment: @Kevin: Correct. If `a` were a class member and the class containing `a` was still rooted and in-use then it too would hang around. That is one scenario where setting it to `null` could be beneficial.

Comment: Your point ties in with a reason why `Dispose` is important--it's not possible to invoke `Dispose` (or any other non-inlineable method) on an object without a rooted reference to it; calling `Dispose` after one is done using an object will ensure that a rooted reference will continue to exist throughout the duration of the last action performed on it.  Abandoning all references to an object without calling `Dispose` may ironically have the effect of causing the object's resources to occasionally get released *too early*.

Comment: This example and explanation doesn't seem definitive on the hard suggestion to never set references to null.  I mean, except for Kevin's comment, a reference set to null **after it is disposed** seems pretty _benign_, so what is the harm? Am I missing something?

Comment: @dathompson setting it to null twice would also be "benign" but that isn't a reason to do so. (ad absurdum...)

Comment: Is there any code analyzer that goes through the code and warns when things that should have been disposed aren't disposed?

Answer (score 18):

You never need to set objects to null in C#. The compiler and runtime will take care of figuring out when they are no longer in scope.

Yes, you should dispose of objects that implement IDisposable.

Comment: If you have a long-lived (or even static) reference to a large object, you `want` to null it out as soon as you're done with it so that it's free to be reclaimed.

Comment: If you're ever "done with it" it shouldn't be static. If it's not static, but "long-lived" then it should still go out of scope soon after you're done with it. The need to set references to null indicates a problem with the structure of the code.

Comment: You can have a static item that you get done with.  Consider:  A static resource that's read from disk in a user-friendly format and then parsed into a format suitable for program use.  You can end up with a private copy of the raw data that serves no further purpose. (Real world example:  The parsing is a two-pass routine and thus can't simply process the data as it's read.)

Comment: Then it should not store any raw data in a static field if it's only used temporarily. Sure, you *can* do that, it's just not good practice for exactly this reason: you then have to manage its lifetime manually.

Comment: How in the world do you avoid it?  You have an object that obtains raw data and processes it.  The processed data persists for the life of the program.  Unless you manually dispose of the raw data the object is still going to retain a reference to it.  Whether the object is static or dynamic is irrelevant.

Comment: You avoid it by storing the raw data in a local variable in the method that processes it. The method returns the processed data, which you keep, but the local for the raw data goes out of scope when the method exits and is automatically GCed.

Comment: "*you never need to set objects to null in C#*" - bit of a wild statement do you have evidence to back that up? If I have a lazily loaded/singleton object and I subsequently call `Dispose` on it there is the potential for me to attempt to use that object after it's been disposed as there is no guarantee that the GC will `null` out the field before it's used again.

Answer (score 13):

If the object implements `IDisposable`, then yes, you should dispose it.  The object could be hanging on to native resources (file handles, OS objects) that might not be freed immediately otherwise.  This can lead to resource starvation, file-locking issues, and other subtle bugs that could otherwise be avoided.

See also [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: But won't the garabage collector call Dispose()?  If so, why would you need to call it?

Comment: Unless you call it explicitly, there is no guarantee that `Dispose` will be called.  Also, if your object is holding on to a scarce resource or is locking some resource (e.g. a file), then you'll want to free it up as soon as possible.  Waiting for the GC to do that is suboptimal.

Comment: GC will never call Dispose(). GC might call a finalizer which by convention should clean up resources.

Comment: @adrianm: Not `might` call, but `will` call.

Comment: @leppie: finalizers are not deterministic and might not be called ( e.g. when the appdomain is unloaded). If you need deterministic finalization you must implement what i think is called a critical handler.  The CLR has special handling of these objects to guarantee that they are finalized (e.g it pre-jits the finalization code to handle low memory)

Comment: @adrianm: I've also found a few odd cases, such as locker objects, where Dispose does things that Finalize does not.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with the common answer here that yes you should dispose and no you generally shouldn't set the variable to null... but I wanted to point out that dispose is NOT primarily about memory management. Yes, it can help (and sometimes does) with memory management, but it's primary purpose is to give you deterministic releasing of scarce resources.

For example, if you open a hardware port (serial for example), a TCP/IP socket, a file (in exclusive access mode) or even a database connection you have now prevented any other code from using those items until they are released. Dispose generally releases these items (along with GDI and other "os" handles etc. which there are 1000's of available, but are still limited overall). If you don't call dipose on the owner object and explicitly release these resources, then try to open the same resource again in the future (or another program does) that open attempt will fail because your undisposed, uncollected object still has the item open. Of course, when the GC collects the item (if the Dispose pattern has been implemented correctly) the resource will get released... but you don't know when that will be, so you don't know when it's safe to re-open that resource. This is the primary issue Dispose  works around. Of course, releasing these handles often releases memory too, and never releasing them may never release that memory... hence all the talk about memory leaks, or delays in memory clean up.

I have seen real world examples of this causing problems. For instance, I have seen ASP.Net web applications that eventually fail to connect to the database (albeit for short periods of time, or until the web server process is restarted) because the sql server 'connection pool is full'... i.e, so many connections have been created and not explicitly released in so short a period of time that no new connections can be created and many of the connections in the pool, although not active, are still referenced by undiposed and uncollected objects and so can't be reused. Correctly disposing the database connections where necessary ensures this problem doesn't happen (at least not unless you have *very* high concurrent access).

Answer (score 10):

If they implement the IDisposable interface then you should dispose them. The garbage collector will take care of the rest.

**EDIT:** best is to use the `using` command when working with disposable items:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("..")){ ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Always call dispose. It is not worth the risk. Big managed enterprise applications should be treated with respect. No assumptions can be made or else it will come back to bite you.

Don't listen to leppie.

A lot of objects don't actually implement IDisposable, so you don't have to worry about them. If they genuinely go out of scope they will be freed automatically. Also I have never come across the situation where I have had to set something to null.

One thing that can happen is that a lot of objects can be held open. This can greatly increase the memory usage of your application. Sometimes it is hard to work out whether this is actually a memory leak, or whether your application is just doing a lot of stuff.

Memory profile tools can help with things like that, but it can be tricky.

In addition always unsubscribe from events that are not needed. Also be careful with WPF binding and controls. Not a usual situation, but I came across a situation where I had a WPF control that was being bound to an underlying object. The underlying object was large and took up a large amount of memory. The WPF control was being replaced with a new instance, and the old one was still hanging around for some reason. This caused a large memory leak.

In hindsite the code was poorly written, but the point is that you want to make sure that things that are not used go out of scope. That one took a long time to find with a memory profiler as it is hard to know what stuff in memory is valid, and what shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 5):

When an object implements `IDisposable` you should call `Dispose` (or `Close`, in some cases, that will call Dispose for you).

You normally do not have to set objects to `null`, because the GC will know that an object will not be used anymore.

There is one exception when I set objects to `null`. When I retrieve a lot of objects (from the database) that I need to work on, and store them in a collection (or array). When the "work" is done, I set the object to `null`, because the GC does not know I'm finished working with it.

Example:

```
using (var db = GetDatabase()) {
    // Retrieves array of keys
    var keys = db.GetRecords(mySelection); 

    for(int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++) {
       var record = db.GetRecord(keys[i]);
       record.DoWork();
       keys[i] = null; // GC can dispose of key now
       // The record had gone out of scope automatically, 
       // and does not need any special treatment
    }
} // end using => db.Dispose is called
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally, there's no need to set fields to null. I'd always recommend disposing unmanaged resources however.

From experience I'd also advise you to do the following:

- Unsubscribe from events if you no longer need them.
- Set any field holding a delegate or an expression to null if it's no longer needed.

I've come across some very hard to find issues that were the direct result of not following the advice above.

A good place to do this is in Dispose(), but sooner is usually better.

In general, if a reference exists to an object the garbage collector (GC) may take a couple of generations longer to figure out that an object is no longer in use. All the while the object remains in memory.

That may not be a problem until you find that your app is using a lot more memory than you'd expect. When that happens, hook up a memory profiler to see what objects are not being cleaned up. Setting fields referencing other objects to null and clearing collections on disposal can really help the GC figure out what objects it can remove from memory. The GC will reclaim the used memory faster making your app a lot less memory hungry and faster.

Comment: What do you mean about 'events and delegates' - what should be 'cleaned up' with these?

Comment: @Craig - I edited my answer. Hopefully this clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I have to answer, too.
The JIT generates tables together with the code from it's static analysis of variable usage.
Those table entries are the "GC-Roots" in the current stack frame. As the instruction pointer advances, those table entries become invalid and so ready for garbage collection.
Therefore: If it is a scoped variable, you don't need to set it to null - the GC will collect the object.
If it is a member or a static variable, you have to set it to null

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but there is one scenario that I don't think has been mentioned here - if class A implements IDisposable, and exposes public properties that are also IDisposable objects, then I think it's good practice for class A not only to dispose of the disposable objects that it has created in its Dispose method, but also to set them to null. The reason for this is that disposing an object and letting it get GCed (because there are no more references to it) are by no means the same thing, although it is pretty definitely a bug if it happens. If a client of Class A does dispose its object of type ClassA, the object still exists. If the client then tries to access one of these public properties (which have also now been disposed) the results can be quite unexpected. If they have been nulled as well as disposed, there will be a null reference exception immediately, which will make the problem easier to diagnose.