# Proper way to dispose of Quartz.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET in an application.  What is the proper way to dispose of Quartz.NET.

Right now I am just doing

```
    if (_quartzScheduler != null)
    {
        _quartzScheduler = null;
    }
```

Is that enough or should I implement a dispose or something in the jobType class?

Seth

Comment: Setting to null does nothing useful in .NET.

Comment: Nothing useful related to disposing objects

Comment: btw ... no need to check the _quartzScheduler for null, just set it ... end result is same and the code clearer

Comment: MaLio...thanks...you are right.  That's an old habit harking back to VBA.  Seth

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
scheduler.Shutdown(waitForJobsToComplete: true);
```

Of course, if you're not on C# 4.0 yet, named parameters don't work:

```
scheduler.Shutdown(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete example but might get you on the right path. I would implement something like this:

```
class customSchedulerClass : IDisposable
{

    private Component component = new Component();
    private bool disposed = false;

    public void scheduleSomeStuff()
    {
        //This is where you would implement the Quartz.net stuff
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(!this=disposed)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                component.dispose;
            }
        }
        disposed = true;
    }       
}
```

Then with this you can do cool stuff like using statements:

```
public static void Main()
{
    using (customSchedulerClass myScheduler = new customSchedulerClass())
    {
        c.scheduleSomeStuff();
    }
    console.WriteLine("Now that you're out of the using statement the resources have been disposed");
}
```

So basically by implementing you code while inheriting the functionality of `IDisposable` you can then us the `using` statement and when you're done it will cleanly dispose your resources and keep things nice and clean. (Disclaimer, again this is not a complete example, just to get you in the right direction).

Answer (score 0):

The docs don't say anything about IScheduler implementing IDisposable.  If you have custom job types that grab and hold resources (file locks, database connections), you can implement IDispoable and override Dispose() on your object to release resources.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we don't need to set an object to null in order to dispose it off.
If an object contains unmanaged resources then it should implement IDisposable (and be called by all its clients).

You can refere [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/c-do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null) similar post.