# .Net c# Application Using Too Much Memory After Process Is Complete

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've made a simple .net application that takes data from a database and saves as an excel document. Problem i have noticed is that once the process has completed and the spreadsheet is generated, the application hogs about 750mb of memory. It is collating a big report, But i thought once it had saved that memory is deallocated?

Is this the case?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the `750 mb of memory` from? You could be looking at the `Working Set` which would be a bad metric to use since pages remain in the Working Set of a process even if they are not in use. Make sure you're looking at private bytes

Answer (score 2):

In .Net memory isn't necessarily deallocated automatically.

You can try to `Dispose()` all large objects that implement IDisposable and/or null out any references to these instances, and then call `GC.Collect()` to force an immediate garbage collection.  This *may* help if you are holding references to large objects after you are done with them.

Comment: If you're going to vote it down, please provide a comment as to what is wrong with the answer.  For my part, this answer is better suited to a comment on the original question.

Comment: I got 2 downvotes almost instantly. I'd really appreciate the downvoters to at least leave a comment as of where I'm headed in the wrong direction.

Comment: @DennisTraub it's better suited as a comment, since your asking a question and not providing a direct answer.

Comment: He was making a statement about how garbage collection works and then offering a solution. How is this not an answer?

Comment: Your answer was more of a WAG and a question back to OP, which I'd think you'd know isn't exactly kosher around here (5k rep and all).  I  believe my edit captures the core of your answer without making it appear to be a comment.  Also, you're right; .the CLR doesn't deallocate memory unless it has to.  Memory hogging is a *good thing*.

Comment: @msarchet I wasn't aware of the fact that the correct choice of sentence structure matters that much. As a non-native speaker I'll be working on my English skills right away. Sorry and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Will thanks for the editing and clarification. And yes, even with 5k rep I wasn't aware of this type of answer not being kosher. Sorry again, English is not my first language.

Comment: @DennisTraub: Understandable.  Also, you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Memory is not deallocated instantly by the Garabage Collector.

Also are you making sure that you are disposing of all of your objects properly, and allowing the garbage collector to pick up the items. In you thoughts of after it is saved, doesn't matter if the item is still being referenced by something in your application.

Comment: Particularly Excel resources as these can take up a lot of memory and could be the cause

Comment: This is true. I have a background worker running to produce the excel document. The Garbage collector will run to deallocated any memory thats no longer being used by the application? GC.Collect() (from the post below)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a memory profiler. Here are some product links:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Answer (score 1):

If the data is still referenced and used by your application, then the memory will not be garbage collected. See [garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)

Also see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null) may help? I found it very useful, especially Igor Zevaka's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check for definitions. For example if you defined forms in your code it will use a lot of ram because of starting same form a lot of times.

For example; I have 3 forms in my application. Form1, Form2 and Form3.

```
namespace RAMAPP 
{
    public partial class RAMAPP : Form
    {
       Form1 first = new Form1();
       Form2 second = new Form2();
       Form3 third = new Form3();

    public RAMAPP()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

In here, when you click start button, program reads all lines you wrote now. And before starting, RAMAPP program defining Forms as first,second and third. The problem is to define these forms before the initializing. 
You should delete all form definitions before the initializing. 
After this, restart your program and it will be run hopefully :)