# Is there any case where we have to set variables to null in C# when disposing them?

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, disposing

If the variable is local to the current scope, is there any reason to set them to null right before the end of it?

```
{
    var com = new AComponentObjectModelInterface();

    // something goes here
    // ...

    com = null; // why?
}
```

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null useful

Comment: @Arion use this syntax for links in comments: `[title](url)`

Comment: The `com` variable is _not_ being disposed in this sample. Unless there is a `using(com)` before the `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the developer that used this was migrating VB6 code manually. But he ignored that

```
Set aComponentObjectModelInstance = new AComponentObjectModelInterface

// something goes here
// ...

Set aComponentObjectModelInstance = Nothing
```

should be translated to

```
var aComponentObjectModelInstance = new AComponentObjectModelInterface();
try 
{
    // something goes here
    // ...
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aComponentObjectModelInstance);
}
```

instead

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, No, not in C#

This is often a habit developers take using other languages like VB6

Comment: I saw this in VB6 too, is there any reason to do that in VB?

Comment: In VB6, yes, it causes COM references to be released.

Comment: It is not necessary to set the object to Nothing in VB6 either, the object will be dereferenced as soon as it is out of scope.  The issue of cleaning up COM objects in the CLR can get quite complex but if you are just creating and finishing with it in one method the answer provided by @XMLforDummies would dereference the object and should cause it to be removed from memory otherwise you just have to wait for the GC to clean it up.  In other cases you should remember that the CLR doesn’t do reference counting and such dereferencing an object can remove the object from memory prenatally.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a variable to null is NOT disposing of the object it references to. In fact it may hinder garbage collection by extending the scope of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: In your particular case, there is no reason whatsoever. Most likely those programmers came from a different language where that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes useful to prevent multiple `Dispose` of the same object. Say you have a `Close` method that does some clean-up on your class. By setting the object to `null`, you'll ensure multiple `Close` call won't try to `Dispose` the `DisposableMember` multiple times:

```
public void Close()
{
    if (DisposableMember != null)
    {
        DisposableMember.Dispose();
        DisposableMember = null;
    }
}
```

But keep in mind *it doesn't free/dispose anything itself.*