# Isolated Storage Operation Not Permitted Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

I have a directory and I'm using a compression tool to compress directory into a zip file but after I finished the zipping operation I get an error saying: isolated storage operation not permitted.

This error only occurs occasionally.

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

C1ZipFile zip = new C1.C1Zip.C1ZipFile();

if (isf.DirectoryExists("SFA_DB") == true)
{
   var fs = isf.CreateFile("\\SFA_DB.zip");
   zip.Create(fs);
   foreach (string fileName in isf.GetFileNames("SFA_DB\\*.*"))
        zip.Entries.Add(isf.OpenFile("SFA_DB\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open), fileName);
   fs.Close();
   fs.Dispose();
   zip.Close();
 }

//Last Two Lines I have writtent recently
isf.Dispose(); 
isf = null;
```

Zipping tool is provided by Component One **C1.Phone.Zip.8**

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Last Two Lines I have writtent recently"? Have you tested the code with those two lines?

Comment: Yeah  I did, and I still get that exception

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading your code correctly, but it seems to me you're trying to add the zip file to itself.  Since you're creating in that directory then opening all files in that directory as well.

Comment: No I have checked that, it's fine too...! Sometimes This Error occurs at the start when I create my first zip file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not disposing the object, to quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317747/c-sharp-object-dispose-or-object-null) answer:

> Setting the object to null may result in leaving out un-managed resources un-disposed. The whole object of having IDisposable is to make sure that un-managed resources are disposed after their usage.

So what I would do: remove the `isf = null;` line and wrap it all in a `using` statement.

Comment: I still get that 'Operation not permitted on  IsolatedStorageFileStream.'