# Should we mark objects readonly if they are fields of an IDisposable class

Tags: c#, idisposable

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

1. I have this class (FooClass) that implements IDisposable which takes another disposable (OtherDisposableClass) as an argument of its constructor.
2. I create an instance of OtherDisposableClass
3. I create an instance of FooClass and pass the instance OtherDisposableClass to it
4. The instance of OtherDisposableClass should not be mutateable so I mark it readonly
5. I can't get rid of the reference to the instance of OtherDisposableClass in my Dispose method

**QUESTION**

What is the best thing to do here? Should we

1. Not mark the instance of OtherDisposableClass as readonly so we can set it to 'null' in the Dispose method
2. Mark OtherDisposableClass as readonly and do not remove the reference to it ever again.
3. Something else

Please elaborate your answer. Thank you

```
public class FooClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly OtherDisposableClass _disposable;
    private readonly string _imageSource;
    private readonly string _action;
    private readonly string _destination;

    private bool _isInitialized;

    public FooClass(OtherDisposableClass disposable)
    {
        _disposable = disposable;
    }
    ~FooClass() 
    {
        // Finalizer calls Dispose(false)
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Not possible because _disposable is marked readonly
        _disposable = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: (2) - unless you had a strong reason for wanting to set it to `null`, you can normally just trust the GC to get things right.

Comment: But you'll keep a reference to that object. Is the GC smart enough to collect the instance of FooClass if there is still a reference to OtherDisposableClass (which will not be disposed yet)? Any docs that explain this? Is it different on Mono (dont know if it has its own GC)?

Comment: Are you really planning to keep your `FooClass` instance around for an extended period of time, having just called `Dispose` on it? That's a rather unusual usage model. If not, it's likely that the `FooClass` instance is going to shortly be garbage itself, so its references will be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that does the creation of `OtherDisposableClass` should be disposing of it... leave it alone in `FooClass` (you can have it `readonly` if you like).

Setting it to null will have no effect anyway, it will only set the reference from within FooClass to null (which is about to be disposed anyway).

**EDIT**

From the code given it looks like you don't even need to implement IDisposable here - this is just over complicating things. If you created an instance of `OtherDisposableClass` within the constructor of `FooClass` then you could implement IDisposable and simply call `OtherDisposableClass.Dispose()` within the `FooClass.Dispose()`.

Here FooClass is created with a dependency on OtherFooClass - OtherFooClass will outlive FooClass - therefore FooClass should be GC'd first and then there will be no reference to OtherDisposableClass remaining - which will allow it to be GC'd

Comment: But you'll keep a reference to that object. Is the GC smart enough to collect the instance of FooClass if there is still a reference to OtherDisposableClass (which will not be disposed yet)?

Comment: Setting it to null **is** helpful in that it gives an extra hint to the GC that this object is no longer in use, and also can prevent usage of an internal member after the `FooClass` object is disposed.

Comment: @Patrick: I've not heard about this before... Could you elaborate (or provide a link) on how setting the OtherDisposableClass reference to null helps with GC?. Here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null top answer with 92 upvotes says setting to null doesn't matter unless we need to make an object go out of scope

Comment: @Ben: That's essentially what I'm referring to.  Imagine you dispose an object but hang on to the reference.  The internal member, if not set to null, is still reachable and so won't be collected.  If you null it out, it can be collected (assuming that's the only reference to it).

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I believe you just explained the problem I'm seeing with readonly fields. So based on your logic (and mine), in the example above, the FooClass instances will never be disposed because they keep a reference to an instance of OtherDisposableClass

Comment: @MrSoundless Don't confuse _disposed_ with _garbage collected_.  And just because `FooClass` has an instance of `OtherDisposableClass` does not mean that `FooClass` will never be garbage collected.  It depends on whether the `FooClass` instance can be reached from the "root" of your application.

Comment: That last sentence helps a lot! So if I get this right: OtherDisposableObject doesn't have to be set to null. If FooObject cannot be reached from the root of the application, it will be collected by the GC and since we call dispose() in the destructor, it will also be disposed.

Comment: This also explains why everyone yells that IDisposable should only be implemented in case the class contains unmanaged objects, since you can just set the managed objects to null (in case they aren't readonly) inside the destructor (I guess we wouldn't even need to). I always had this weird thought that an object would only be GC'd in a case where no objects have a reference to it, and it has no references to other objects. Thank you! I would mark this as the right answer if you would commit it as an answer.

Comment: @MrSoundless Unless you are writing code that interoperates with unmanaged code, and know what you are doing, do not write destructors is C#. Forgive me for saying so, but given the questions you are asking, you should not be writing destructors.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk - it appears to me that in this instance OtherFooClass should outlive FooClass (as FooClass depends on it), so once FooClass is GC'd there will be no reference to OtherFooClass, hence it will also be GC'd - I still don't see how setting it to null is necessary.

Comment: @Ben You're right, but if FooClass cannot be GC'd (e.g. if some object hangs on to a reference to it), then OtherFooClass cannot be GC'd either.  However, if you clear FooClass's reference to OtherFooClass, then at least the OtherFooClass instance can be collected in the same situation.

Comment: @Ben setting a member type IDisposable to null is the correct thing to do in Dispose(bool diposing) see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspxv

Answer (score 1):

The `IDisposable` interface allows you to release unmanaged resources in a deterministic way. Unmanaged resources can be file handles, database connections etc. Disposing an object does not release any memory. Memory is only reclaimed by the garbage collector and you have very little control of when and how that is done. **Disposing an object does not free any memory**.

Still there is a connection between garbage collection and `IDisposable`. If your class directly controls an unmanaged resource it should release this resource during finalization. However, having a finalizer on a class has a performance impact and should be avoided if possible. `FooClass` does not directly control an unmanaged resource and the finalizer is not needed. However, to enforce the deterministic release of unmanaged resources it is important the `FooClass.Dispose` calls `OtherDisposableClass.Dispose` when `Dispose` is called explictly (when `disposing` is `true`). If `Dispose` is called from the finalizer you should not call methods on other managed objects because these objects may already have been finalized.

So to sum it up:

- Garbage collection and reclaiming of memory is distinct from releasing unmanaged resources.
- The `Dispose` method should always release unmanaged resource.
- The `Dispose` method should call `Dispose` on aggregated objects but only when called directly (not when called from the finalizer).
- It should be possible to call `Dispose` multiple times without any problems.
- There is no point in setting an `IDisposable` field to `null` in the `Dispose` method.
- Avoid implementing finalizers if you do not control any unmanaged resources directly.
- When implementing `IDisposable` you have to take inheritance into consideration because both the base class and the derived class may want to call `Dispose` on fields and/or release unmanaged resources. Sealing a class can avoid a lot of this complexity.

To elaborate on the point about setting the field to `null`:

I assume that your code is sane. E.g., only `FooClass` has a permanent reference to `OtherDisposableClass` and both objects will after disposal be unusable (e.g. throw `ObjectDisposedException` in all public methods except `Dispose`).

If you set the reference to `OtherDisposableClass` to `null` then that instance becomes eligible for garbage collection because there are no references to the instance. However, after disposing `FooClass` you surely will not keep an reference to that instance because it is unusable. This means that both the `FooClass` and the `OtherDisposableClass` are no longer reachable from a [GC root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) and the entire object graph is now eligible for garbage collection. So there is no need to sever the link between `FooClass` and `OtherDisposableClass` because they will become eligible for garbage collection at the same time.

Comment: My advice against finalizers would be even stronger (simply *don't* use them unless you understand all the issues).  In almost all cases, the effort that would be required to write a finalizer that works correctly in all cases where it possibly can would be better spent making sure one's objects don't leak.  Finalizers should generally only be necessary when dealing with third-party code which is incapable of properly tracking object lifetimes.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, if a type which implements `IDisposable` has any variables that are declared `WithEvents`, it is generally a good idea--and is sometimes very important--to set those variables to `null` in the `Dispose` method, since failure to do so will mean that objects to which those variables referred will be left holding back-references to the object that was disposed.  That can cause serious memory leaks in the scenario where many short-lived objects subscribe to events from a long-lived object.

Although C# does not allow VB.NET-style `WithEvents` declarations, it's possible to code properties in C# which behave similarly:

```
// Handle a property Wobbler which identifies an object whose Wibbled event
// I want to handle with my WibbleWobble method.
Woozle _wobble;
Woozle Wobbler {
  get { return _wobbler; }
  set {
    var wasWobbler = _wobbler
    if (wasWobbler == value) return; // Don't unsubcribe and resubscribe same object
    if (wasWobbler != null)
      wasWobbler.Wibbled -= WibbleWobble; // Unsubscribe old event
    if (value != null)
      value.Wibbled += WibbleWobble; // Subscribe new event
    _wobbler = value;
  }
};
```

If one uses a pattern such as that (it can be a nice way to ensure subscribes get paired up with unsubscribes), one should set `Wobbler` to `null` in one's `Dispose` method, to ensure that any event that was attached to it gets detached.

Other than the aforementioned scenarios, it generally doesn't matter whether `Dispose` sets things to `null`, since the only thing one should be doing with the objects referred to by those fields is disposing them and cancelling their events, calling `Dispose` multiple times on a well-coded object should be harmless.  There are a few cases, however, were setting a field to `null` in dispose may be helpful.  Some collections store data using an array along with an indication of which slots hold meaningful data; if a collection "removes" an item from the array by indicating a slot doesn't hold anything meaningful, but doesn't null out the reference, that item *and anything to which it holds a direct or indirect reference* will be kept alive by the GC.  If disposed objects null out their references to other objects, the amount of data kept alive by the collection may be minimized.

Incidentally, note that the code above is not thread safe, and cannot very cleanly be made thread-safe without locking, even if the subscribe/unsubscribe methods are thread safe and one uses only accesses `_wobbler` via `Interlocked` methods.  If `_wobbler` is updated before subscriptions/unsubscriptions are processed, then if `Wobbler` is to some object George in one thread and to something else in another, the second thread might send George an unsubscribe request before the first thread has sent its subscription request (resulting in a dangling subscription).  If it's not updated before processing subscriptions/unsubscriptions, then two simultaneous attempts to set Wobbler to George could result in George being given two consecutive subscription requests (which could eventually result in a dangling subscription).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in setting you member `IDisposable` to null in `Dispose(bool disposing)`, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx

As you cannot if the field is marked `readonly` the solution is I am afraid to remove the `readonly`.