# Should a UdpClient be disposed of?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, dispose, udpclient

When trying to dispose of a UdpClient, I found that it's impossible. For the following:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Dispose();
```

Visual Studio shows an error:

> 'System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level

Does this mean that I should inherit from `UdpClient` and expose the `Dispose` (Since it seems to be the consensus that [whatever implements IDisposable should be disposed of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null))? Is there some reason we shouldn't use the class directly? Or is there simply nothing to dispose of after calling `Close`?

Though a `using` statement *does* work - it's not suitable when listening.

Comment: If you were supposed to inherit from it, the constructors would be protected too, but they're public. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.dispose.aspx) is definitely misleading.

Comment: `protected virtual void UdpClient.Dispose(Boolean)` has been around since .NET framework 2.0 whereas the parameter-less overload `public void Dispose()` is only available since 4.6. Your project is targeting framework < 4.6 so you only see the protected method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you shouldn't.
you should call `UdpClient.Close` ...

---

After looking at the source here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs#7682e0ea2c48b5cb

It appears you can either call `Close` or `((IDisposable)updClient).Dispose` but API-wise I think calling `Close` is the way UDP client is intended to be used...

All this makes very little sense to me....

Comment: Since it seems to be the consensus that [whatever implements IDisposable should be disposed of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null) - Do you have a source?

Comment: This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360027.aspx

Comment: @ispiro it's basically a design flaw from .Net 1.1

Comment: +1 Thanks. That's a pretty clear source! Although, I'll admit I now don't understand this whole `UdpClient.IDisposable.Dispose` thing, and why doesn't [the documentation for UdpClient.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mention that. Perhaps there are two separate `Dispose` methods here... Anyway - thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ispiro looking at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs#7682e0ea2c48b5cb) I don't get it. 'UdpClient.Close' is identical to 'UdpClient.IDisposable.Dispose'

Comment: I think the `UdpClient.IDisposable.Dispose` API doc is for an [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) back in .NET 4.5.2. I don't see that API in the reference source, which is for 4.8, so I guess they got rid of it (?). I think that explains the confusion, at least for me.