# C# Keywords Implement IDispose

Tags: c#, keyword, dispose

What keywords implement or will call dispose() in the background in C#?  When is it necessary to explicitly call dispose on versus using IDispose?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about. I think you may be confused, could you add more details and maybe and example?

Comment: Does `DisposableObject.Dispose()` not help you?

Comment: Do you mean like the way a `using` block implicitly disposes at the end?

Comment: Check these two answers on the same question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926890/3773066) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926928/3773066).  Also, read up on the [IDisposable.Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Firstly, the interface is called IDisposable. Dispose can be implemented by classes which are derived from this interface.
The only keyword I know of which is using dispose is "using". 
Despose might also be called during garbage collection by the destructor but do not rely on this!
For more info maybe take a look at the dispose pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If an object implements `IDispose`, then yes, call `Dispose` on the object.

For example, objects with a using block:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
  //...
}
```

Here is some more information on [Implementing the Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

EDIT: Also this old Stack Overflow post is really great: [Do you need to dispose of objects and set them to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null)