# Dispose found in existing C# code. Should I get rid of it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, dispose

I found the following code in a Unity3D project using the Kinect v2 which I have taken over. I'm paranoid so I thought I'd check before I delete it.
But surely there is no reason for these two lines??

```
colorFrame.Dispose();
colorFrame = null;
```

This is C#. It has automatic garbage collection so my understanding is that colorFrame will be disposed when its convenient outside of the if(GetRGB) statement

```
if (GetRGB)
{
    ColorFrame colorFrame = frame.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame ();
    if (colorFrame != null)
    {
        colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray (_ColorData, ColorImageFormat.Rgba);
        _ColorTexture.LoadRawTextureData (_ColorData);
        _ColorTexture.Apply ();
        colorFrame.Dispose ();
        colorFrame = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you need to dispose of objects and set them to null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It has automatic garbage collection so my understanding is that
>   colorFrame will be disposed when its convenient outside of the
>   if(GetRGB) statement

The object will be cleaned once that GC kicks in (at a non-deterministic time) and sees there is no root to the `colorFrame` object. Calling `Dispose` on an object usually releases unmanaged resources allocated by that same object, as well as calls `GC.SupressFinalize`, which makes any object that has a finalizer de-register from the finalization queue, allowing the GC to clean it up "faster".

I would suggest keeping the call to `Dispose`. I would remove the `colorFrame = null` call, which is useless.

Better yet, wrap `colorFrame` in a `using` statement:

```
if (GetRGB)
{
    using (ColorFrame colorFrame = frame.ColorFrameReference.AcquireFrame()) 
    {
        if (colorFrame != null)
        {
           colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(_ColorData, ColorImageFormat.Rgba);
           _ColorTexture.LoadRawTextureData(_ColorData);
           _ColorTexture.Apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be *garbage collected* at a non-deterministic future time.  If the class has been written correctly, it will include an internal call to `Dispose`.

However, you should always call `Dispose` (or better, use a `using` block) on `IDisposable` objects as that way they can release any unmanaged resources they are currently holding on to without waiting for the framework to perform a garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection is part of the CLR. IDisposable is an arbitrary interface that is used to clean on resources used by a class when it finishes its life. DON'T REMOVE DISPOSE!!! The framework knows nothing of Dipose() and won't call it.