# Should we call dispose method for NSDate in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Due to memory leak problem, I have cleared my objects after leaving my component page, where I have called the `dispose` for NSDate variable.
My question is,
Should we call `dispose` for NSDate variable or it will automatically `dispose` while leave the page. Please share your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see the lifecycle of an object written in

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSObject/#Lifecycle

> When you create an object from C# using the "new" operator, the object
>   will initially be owned by C#, and C# will retain a reference to the
>   object. This reference will only be dropped when the garbage collector
>   determines that there are no pending managed references to it,or when
>   you manually call the Dispose method on the object.

Objects will be cleaned up automatically by garbage collector when there are no pending managed references to it.

Back to you question, you know that NSDate inherits from NSObject,so when you create a instance of NSDate, the instance's lifecycle is managed by garbage collector. When you leave your page, the instance will no longer be used and it will be cleaned up by garbage collector automatically.

So,you can call dispose method to clean up it but overall there is usually no need to do that.

Here is a similar issue link that might help you:

[Do you need to dispose of objects and set them to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null)

Answer (score 0):

garbage collector only Collect the C# based Variable.but the Nsobject will not collect by the garbage collector.so we have to remove manually. By using the dispose method.