# C# how to look for class with unmanaged resource?

Tags: c#, resources, unmanaged

So... I usually deal with the comfy managed code side of C#, but now I have to add finalizer for any class with unmanaged resource. I read about finalizer and IDisposable already, but I don't really know all the various numerous different ways to acquire and release unmanaged resource in C# so I don't know what to look for.

Is the GCHandle.Alloc and .Free pair the only one out there? What else is there?

Comment: If this is a real problem then you have a specific unm. resource. No need to look at all other forms of resources...

Comment: First check: [do you really need it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3510513/60761)

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to handle unmanaged resources in C# is with the `SafeHandle` class

See also

- [SafeHandle: A Reliability Case Study [Brian Grunkemeyer]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/16/396900.aspx)
- [Never Write a Finalizer again](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=86c71425-57bc-4fcb-b34b-3262812f12cf) from Joe Duffy.